# FBX SDK and C++ IO [crash]

Tags: c++, io, fbx

When I’m using for example **FILE* pFile;** or **fstream file;** after initializing fbx and Loading a FBX file, the programms stops and I get a invalid Heap error.
I wasn’t able to find a solution for this problem. The Error comes right after the function

`lImporter->Initialize(filename.c_str(), -1, pSdkManager->GetIOSettings());`

Is this a common problem, is there a trick to use any IO class and FBX together?

Version = 2012.2

dll = fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib

Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Comment: Does it cache the first argument, if so, when is `filename` destructed?

Comment: lImporter->Initialize is part of a function and filename is the parameter. The wired thing is that if i dont use fstream of FILE* in the whole proj. the function works fine.

Comment: The soultion was to set a allocater class. 

    bxSdkManager::SetMemoryAllocator(&lMyMemoryAllocator);

It is mentioned in the Examples which came with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `File*` to `char[]`. This should resolve your crashing problem:

```
char fileName[] = "file.fbx";

Model yourModel (fileName);
```

FBX SDK will read your model as is (no need to include `fstream` in this case).

(If it doesn't work, upgrade to the lastest FBX SDK 2013. I'm using VS2012)